# Jquery Close menu div on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which opens when I click a menu button, I am trying to close it if the user clicks anywhere after it is open. The issue I am having is that with my code the show div and the close div when a user clicks I guess are firing at the same time for some reason. The code for the click event is below. How can I make it so they do not fire at the same time and when I open the div that does not fire the click function. Thanks!

```
//if user clicks and menu is open then hide menu div
$(document).click(function() { 
       if($("menu").hasClass("menu_closed") == false ) { 
           //will hide the menu div
           closeMenu();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want actually is to stop propagation in the other click handler, something like:

```
$("your_menu_selector").bind("click", function(e){

   //your code to open the menu

   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding the event handler to close the menu in the handler that opens the menu.  Have it execute only once using the `one` method. In the handler that opens the menu, simply check to see if it is open already and do a no-op if it is.

```
 $('.openButton').click( function() {
      var $menu = $('#menu').
      if ($menu.hasClass('menu_closed')) {
         $menu.removeClass('menu_closed').addClass('menu_open');
         $(document).one( function() {
             $menu.removeClass('menu_open').addClass('menu_closed');
         });
      }
 });
```

Comment: but wont this only work when specifically clicking on the open button. I want the menu to close if I click anywhere sort of like a windows style menu.

Comment: No.  When the open button is clicked, it adds a handler to the document that will execute one time and will close the menu when you click anywhere on the page.